# Can the word after "the same" be plural?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

Is the sentence

> The same character in different locations will be converted to different symbols

correct? Should *character* be *characters* so that it can match the plural form of *different symbols*?

Comment: Hello and welcome. First, note that *will be convert* is not a good English expression. Do you mean *will be converted* (the future passive)? Second, even if you change *will be convert* to *will be converted* it is not clear what your sentence means. What do you mean by symbols?

Comment: Hi @Clare . Yes, *will be convert* is a typo, it should be *will be converted*. I have fixed it in my question. Thanks for pointing it out! For the meaning of this sentence, I want to describe an information encoding process in computer science. For example, maybe I can encode the text "aaa" as "123", where "1", "2" and "3" represent 3 different symbols. And in this sentence, I want to emphasize that the text "aaa" (the same character "a" that appears 3 times) will never be encoded as "111" (a symbol "1" that appears 3 times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes you can use a singular or a plural in the context you give, and yes, the example you give is grammatically correct:

> The same *character* in different locations will be converted to different *symbols*.

I assume that this is from the documentation for a computer program and referring to an ASCII character, or character on a computer keyboard.

Let's say a computer program was written to remove duplicate characters by changing them to a different character, because no character from the alphabet *or* symbol can be used more than once. So if you typed "*A, B, C*" that is fine; but if you typed "*A, B, A*" it automatically changed the second '*A*' to an exclamation mark '*!*'. You could say:

> The duplicate *character* has been converted to *a different symbol*.

This is because a singular character "*A*" has been changed to a singular character "*!*"

So now let's say you typed "*A, A, A*" and the program removed the duplicates by changing it to "*A, !, $*". Now you would have to say:

> The duplicate *characters* have been converted to *different symbols*.

Both *characters* and *symbols* are plural because there are two *A*s that require exchanging and they are exchanged for two different symbols.

Your example is correct though because it speaks of "*the same character*". As a character in the alphabet, there is only one letter A! So when you identify it as a character it is singular.

It would be rather like saying:

> The same animal in different pens will be relocated to different zoos.

When you are identifying an animal, you speak of it in singular terms, ie "*that is **a** giraffe*". It doesn't matter that there can be many giraffes.